# sytax error while using list comprehensions with dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not sure why i'm getting a syntax error with this comprehension

```
[mydict[k] for mydict in dlist if k in mydict else 'NOT PRESENT']
```

the error is pretty generic "Syntax error - Invalid syntax"

A more simplified statement seems to work fine

```
[mydict[k] for mydict in dlist]
```

can someone tell me whats causing the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to remove else 'NOT PRESENT'? I don't think it's a valid syntax.

Comment: Where does `k` get set? Outside the list comprehension?

Comment: You can't use else like that in a list comprehension

Comment: @Marius yes k and dlist are set earlier. sorry i forgot to mention that

Comment: @DavidRobinson are you sure?this is another statement that's in the course i'm following  mydict[’Oracle’] if ’Oracle’ in mydict else ’NOT PRESENT’

Comment: That's a ternary operator, not a list comprehension. You can put the ternary operator at the start of the list comprehension, see the answers below: but it has nothing to do with the list comprehension per se (no more than `f(x)` is part of list comprehension syntax because you can do `[[f(x) for x in lst])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The if/else and the for need to be swapped:

```
[mydict[k] if k in mydict else 'NOT PRESENT' for mydict in dlist]
```

You could shorten this by using `get(k[,d])`:

```
[mydict.get(k, 'NOT PRESENT') for mydict in dlist]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `if` fragment of a list comprehension is *not* part of a ternary expression.

```
[mydict[k] if k in mydict else 'NOT PRESENT' for mydict in dlist]
```

Comment: Does that mean I can't use if-else as filter in list-comprehensions but only if?

Comment: In that part of the list comprehension, yes.